# What do I gain from using Profile or cProfile

Tags: python, profiling

versus something like this:

```
def time_this(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def what_time_is_it(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.clock()
        print 'STARTING TIME: %f' % start_time
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.clock()
        print 'ENDING TIME: %f' % end_time
        print 'TOTAL TIME: %f' % (end_time - start_time)
        return result
     return what_time_is_it
```

I am asking because writing a descriptor likes this seems easier and clearer to me. I recognize that profile/cprofile attempts to estimate bytecode compilation time and such(and subtracts those times from the running time), so more specifically.

I am wondering:

- a) when does compilation time become significant enough for such
  differences to matter?
- b) How might I go about writing my own    profiler that takes into
  account compilation time?

Answer (score 5):

Profile is slower than cProfile, but does support Threads.

cProfile is a lot faster, but AFAIK it won't profile threads (only the main one, the others will be ignored).

Answer (score 1):

Profile and cProfile have **nothing** to do with estimating compilation time. They estimate **run time**.

Compilation time isn't a performance issue. Don't want your code to be compiled every time it's run? `import` it, and it will be saved as a `.pyc`, and only recompiled if you change it. It simply doesn't matter how long code takes to compile (it's very fast) since this doesn't have to be done every time it's run.

If you want to time compilation, you can use the [compiler package](http://docs.python.org/library/compiler.html).

Basically:

```
from timeit import timeit
print timeit('compiler.compileFile(' + filename + ')', 'import compiler', number=100)
```

will print the time it takes to compile `filename` 100 times.

If inside `func`, you append to some lists, do some addition, look up some variables in dictionaries, `profile` will tell you how long each of those things takes.

Your version doesn't tell you any of those things. It's also pretty inaccurate -- the time you get depends on the time it takes to look up the `clock` attribute of `time` and then call it.

If what you want is to time a short section of code, use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html). If you want to [profile](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) code, use `profile` or `cProfile`. If what you want to know is **how long arbitrary code took to run**, but not what parts of it where the slowest, then your version is fine, **so long as the code doesn't take just a few miliseconds**.

Comment: ack, sorry, what I meant by my comment was that -- I recognize cProfile and Profile subtract compilation time from actually running time. I am going to edit the post now.

Comment: I also answer your question about what `profile` does that your version doesn't do. It tells you line by line how much time your function took, how much time it took doing each individual thing, not just the total running time.